# Picard Theorem for Locally Lipschitz functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

In order to apply the local Picard theorem in this question, one of the conditions I must satisfy is that $|f|\leq M$.

Which part of the question can this be inferred from?

Comment: Continuous $\implies$ locally bounded. Continuously differentiable $\implies$ locally Lipschitz.

Comment: I understand continuous functions are bounded on closed bounded sets, however $W$ here is open so $f$ is not neccesarily bounded on the entire set

Comment: @usainlightning To apply existence theorem, you don't need the boundedness of $f$ in the entire $W$, you just need the boundedness of $f$ in a small neighbourhood of $p_0 := x_1(b)$, and you have it.

Comment: @Voliar Is [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Picard%27s_Existence_Theorem) version of the existence+ uniqueness theorem incorrrect? It states that $f$ must be bounded on the entirety of $D$ ($W$ in this question).

Comment: @usainlightning This theorem in correct (see my answer). Note that in your case $D \neq W$.

Answer (score -1):

According to the Hint, you need to show that there exists $h > 0$, such that the problem
$$
x' = f(x), \quad x(b) = p_0 \qquad \qquad (1)
$$
has a unique solution on the interval $(b-h, b+h)$.

Since $p_0 \in W$ and $W$ is open, there exists sufficiently small neighbourhood $U$ of the point $p_0 = x(b)$, such that $U \subset W$.

Since $f$ is continuously differentiable on $W$ and $U$ is a "strict" subset of $W$, there exists $M > 0$ such that $|f(x)| < M$ for all $x \in U$. Moreover, $f$ is, of course, Lipschitz in $U$.

Let us denote $D := \mathbb{R} \times U$. Then we can directly apply [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Picard%27s_Existence_Theorem) theorem (all assumptions will be satisfied) and obtain some $h > 0$, such that (1) possesses a unique solution $x(t)$ on the interval $(b-h, b+h)$. This is the desired result.

That is why you don't need the boundedness of $f$ in the whole $W$ (and, in general, you surely don't have it).